# How to make a worker thread?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to make a worker thread because there is huge load of work on my main thread. This triggers an ANR. I don't know how to make a worker thread or how it works. Can you tell me how to make a working thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `AsyncTask` when it comes about performing long/background operations and showing its result on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads.

Check this out : http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.U9Z5cqYgR0w

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of mechanizm to implement "working thread" in Android: Async Task, threads, Loaders,
IntentService. You should select one of these mechanizm depends from desired functionality.
There are a lot of libraries to implement specific functionality, for example for loading json  from the server and mapping it to objects there is "retrofit" where you can set executor of threads.